# apply sum after the union query in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a sql query in MS-ACCESS 2010 as below:

```
SELECT 
    EXC AS MY_EXC, 
    COUNT(FC_CUSIP) AS MY_FC_CUSIP
FROM 
    TESTDATA  t 
WHERE 
    FC_CUSIP <> "NULL" 
GROUP BY 
    EXC
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    EXC AS MY_EXC, 
    0 AS MY_FC_CUSIP
FROM 
    TESTDATA  t 
WHERE 
    FC_CUSIP = "NULL" 
GROUP BY 
    EXC
ORDER BY 
    MY_EXC ASC;
```

result is as below:

```
MY_EXC  |   MY_FC_CUSIP
--------+---------------
AA      |   0
AM      |   0
AM      |   9
BB      |   0
DD      |   10
DD      |   0
F       |   0
I       |   0
NM      |   0
NM      |   131
NY      |   0
NY      |   184
OO      |   0
OO      |   14
PC      |   0
VA      |   0
Z       |   0
Z       |   2
```

I need a further sql which can give result like as below :
Basically it will distinct MY_EXC and sum that MY_FC_CUSIP

```
MY_EXC  |   MY_FC_CUSIP
--------+---------------
AA      |   0
AM      |   9    
BB      |   0    
DD      |   10
F       |   0
I       |   0
NM      |   131
NY      |   184
OO      |   14
PC      |   0
VA      |   0
Z       |   2
```

Please help me in any way...actually I am creating this whole sql string dynamically via VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.MY_EXC, SUM(a.MY_FC_CUSIP)
FROM (SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, COUNT(FC_CUSIP) AS MY_FC_CUSIP
      FROM TESTDATA  t 
      WHERE FC_CUSIP <> "NULL" 
      GROUP BY EXC
      UNION ALL
      SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC, 0 AS MY_FC_CUSIP
      FROM TESTDATA  t 
      WHERE FC_CUSIP = "NULL" 
      GROUP BY EXC) 
GROUP BY a.MY_EXC
```

Comment: it gives syntax error (missing operation) in query operation 'a.MY_EXC SUM(a.MY_FC_CUSIP)'

Comment: @purnendumaity try now, missed a comma

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does not support `union` in subqueries.  However, in your case, you can simplify the query:

```
SELECT EXC AS MY_EXC,
       SUM(IIF(FC_CUSIP <> "NULL", 1, 0)) AS MY_FC_CUSIP
FROM TESTDATA
GROUP BY EXC
ORDER BY MY_EXC ASC;
```

Comment: ...it is giving correct result but asking dialogue box warning like enter parameter for "MY_EXC" with ok/cancel dialogue box, if I just click 2 time ok/cancel then only it gives results.......I am running whole thing via VBA in backend...so how to progress or any other way ?

Comment: @Gordon...got it... I have to remove this ORDER BY MY_EXC ASC;  clause anyway without that data is coming in proper order in EXC column